# Every time i press remove button it removes the last item

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

When plus button pressed , new From be added to the screen ,and every form has own remove button that call the *removeUserForm* function form HomePageState class. but the problem is when every remove button pressed it removes the last item , but as i expected just the form that owned of remove button should be removed.
why this happen?

i uploaded the full code in Github: https://github.com/geek-sajjad/dynamic_form

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

 List<UserForm> _userForms = <UserForm>[];

  void removeUserForm(User user){
    var find =_userForms.firstWhere((userForm) => userForm.user == user);
    if(find!=null){
      _userForms.removeAt(_userForms.indexOf(find));
    }
    setState(() {

    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _userForms.add(UserForm(              
              onRemoved: removeUserForm,
              user: User(),
            ));
          });
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
          itemBuilder: (ctx, int index) {
            return _userForms[index];
          },
          itemCount: _userForms.length,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



class UserForm extends StatelessWidget {
  final User user;
  final Function onRemoved;
  UserForm({this.user, this.onRemoved, });  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 6,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              onChanged: (value){
                this.user.email = value;
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Email",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),

              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20,),
            TextField(
              onChanged: (value){
                this.user.name = value;
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Name",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10,),
            RaisedButton(onPressed: (){              
              this.onRemoved(this.user);
            }, child: Text("Remove"),),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, you could use a Column wrapped in a SingleChildScrollView like this. I think it's a bad Idea to use the ListView.builder widget implementation here

```
child: SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    children: _userForms,
  ),
),
```

Next, you have to add a Key to your UserForm widget and set a unique key for all forms you add (an increment for example). Flutter needs this key to know which widget is (re)drawing.

```
_userForms.add(UserForm(
  key: Key('$uniqueFormIndex'),
  onRemoved: removeUserForm,
  user: User(),
));
```

Finally, you can simplify your remove method by passing the form itself.

```
void removeUserForm(UserForm userForm) {
setState(() {
  _userForms.remove(userForm);
});
```

Change the constructor of your UserForn wiget

```
UserForm({
  Key key,
  this.user,
  this.onRemoved,
}) : super(key: key);
```

And change the onRemoved

```
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    this.onRemoved(this);
  },
  child: Text("Remove"),
),
```

Comment: thank's , can you explain a little bit about Key and why that problem happen when i don't use the Key ?

Comment: I'll couldn't do better than this article https://medium.com/flutter/keys-what-are-they-good-for-13cb51742e7d :)